# out of Bound exception in Array

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
int n,sum=0;
n=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] arr=new int[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    arr[i]=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
foreach(int j in arr)
{
    sum+=arr[j];
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
i/p:6
    1
    2
    3
    4
    10
    11
```

my o/p:Unhandled Exception:
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at HelloWorld.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00047] in <616dca5eba0b41f0841fc3be1ba6dff5>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at HelloWorld.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00047] in <616dca5eba0b41f0841fc3be1ba6dff5>:0

expected o/p:31

Comment: `foreach` doesn’t do what you seem to think it does. Please read documentation on it and/or debug line by line to see what it does.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add all the values stored in arr.
you were trying to use the input value as a index.

foreach(int j in arr){ sum+=j;}

Comment: could it possible to get array of input from user in a single Line??

Comment: if you want input like 5 2 7 3 get input and split it with " " and conver to int